# Show 80-character margin line in TextMate

Tags: coding-style, formatting, textmate

Is it possible to display a right-margin line at 80 characters in TextMate?  (i.e. the right-margin line in eclipse, gedit, etc.)  If so, how can I configure that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Figured it out:

In the View menu, uncheck 'Soft Wrap'.  Then, go to View -> Wrap Column -> Other... and select the column at 80 chars in your editor window.

This will show the line at 80 characters, but won't force wrapping at 80 chars.  (Turning 'Soft Wrap' back on will force wrapping.)

Comment: Good job! I now love textmate even more, thanks to you, sir :)

Comment: Great answer!  Never would have guessed - I kept hunting around 'Preferences' scratching my head.

Comment: If you want the line to show where it will wrap, you also need to make sure that you've selected  View -> "Show Wrap Column"; otherwise it will wrap but not show you a line where it will wrap.

Answer (score 24):

What about Visual Ornaments/Show right margin indicator in Preferences?

[image: Textmate pref]

Answer (score 10):

For TextMate 2 it looks like this has moved to View -> Show Wrap Column.

So the column can be set at View -> Wrap Column, then shown/hidden using View -> Show/Hide Wrap Column.

[image]